# Placing a form/text box onto Chrome's omnibar

Tags: text

I'm brand new to Chrome Extension creation and was hoping someone could direct me to some documentation specific to my goals.

I'd like to create a form-like text box ([screenshot of text-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvIO6.jpg)) that sits on the Chrome omnibar where the Extension icons stack up. I'd like to be able to type plain text into this box while web-browsing. Also, I'd like to be able to tap Ctrl+K and have the cursor jump into this box and highlight whatever's there for easy copy/pasting.

Essentially, I want to use Firefox's search-bar/box presentation in Chrome as a scratch-pad for taking plain text notes while web-browsing.

I followed the elementary documentation on creating an extension and the HTML I wrote works well in presentation when clicking the icon-button. But I don't want to have to click a button. I just want the Form box to exist on the omnibar persistently and I also want to access it via Ctrl+K.

Can anybody help?

Here's the HTML I wrote (looks just like the Firefox search-bar/box):

```
    <html>
      <form action="">
        <p>
          <input type="text" size="40" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is the closing tag of input missing or is this a typo?

Comment: typo. fixed. Thanks!